# SUBQUERY in NSPredicate and NSInvalidArgumentException

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate, one-to-many

I set up the following model in Core Data.

```
Book has a to-many relationship, called toBookOrders, with OrderBook entity. The inverse is called toBook.
Book has a BOOL value property called isSync.
```

I set up the following `NSPredicate`.

```
NSEntityDescription* entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Book" inManagedObjectContext:moc];
NSPredicate* predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"isSync == 0 AND SUBQUERY(toBookOrders, $x, $x.toBook == SELF)"];
```

Through this predicate I need to grab only books that haven't been synchronized and theirs relative orders.

This is the error I receive.

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to parse the format
>   string "isSync == 0 AND SUBQUERY(toBookOrders, $x, $x.toBook == SELF)"

Any ideas? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Here's the crux of your problem:

```
@"isSync == 0 AND SUBQUERY(toBookOrders, $x, $x.toBook == SELF)"
```

If you split that up into the two subpredicates, as Scott suggests, you'll get:

- `isSync == 0`
- `SUBQUERY(toBookOrders, $x, $x.toBook == SELF)`

The problem is that every `SUBQUERY` does not return true or false, as a predicate must.  It returns a collection (an array), and an array is not the same thing as true or false.  Thus, when you create the predicate, you're getting an error that it's an invalid format, because the stuff after the `AND` *isn't a predicate*.  It's simply an expression.

You're *probably* wanting:

```
@"isSync == 0 AND SUBQUERY(toBookOrders, $x, $x.toBook == SELF).@count > 0"
```

This would give you a predicate to find all the books where `isSync` is false and the at least one of the Book's `OrderBooks` is that Book.

Comment: Thank you very much Dave. Nice explanation. Could I reach the same result also with ANY? Thank you.

Comment: @Flex_Addicted yep, you could do `...AND ANY toBookOrders.toBook == SELF`

Comment: I love you <3 Very useful indeed!

Comment: Thank you. I was struggling with this for sometime.

Comment: Thanks Dave for your perfect answer :)

Answer (score -2):

Separate the `isSync == 0` and `SUBQUERY` into separate `NSPredicate`s, add them to an `NSArray` then use `[NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:array]` to get them joined into a single one to pass to your `NSFetchSpecification`.

Comment: Thank you. The problem is still there. Maybe it's not possible to use *SELF* in subqueries. Thank you.

Comment: Here's how I've used it: `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(childItems, $child, $child.columnName IN %@).@count != 0", arrayOfThingsToMatchOn]`. Self should be implicit, I think.

Comment: -1 This is no different than using `AND` in the predicate format.