# NSPredicate SUBQUERY aggregates

Tags: core-data, nspredicate

In all of the examples I've seen of `SUBQUERY`, `@count` is always used, e.g.,

```
SUBQUERY(employees, $e, $e.lastName == "Smith").@count > 0
```

So I have three very closely related questions, which work best as a single StackOverflow question:

1. Is there any use for `SUBQUERY` without `@count`? If so, I haven't found it.
2. Can any other aggregates be used with `SUBQUERY`? If so, I haven't been able to get them to work. (See below.)
3. What exactly does `SUBQUERY` return? The logical thing seems to be a filtered collection of the type of the first parameter. (I'm speaking conceptually here. Obviously the SQL will be something different, as SQL debugging shows pretty plainly.)

This gives an exception, as does every other aggregate I've tried other than `@count`, which seems to show that no other aggregates can be used:

```
SUBQUERY(employees, $e, $e.lastName == "Smith").@avg.salary > 75000
```

(Let's leave aside for the moment whether this is the best way to express such a thing. The question is about `SUBQUERY`, **not** about how best to formulate a query.)

Mundi helpfully pointed out that another use for `SUBQUERY` is nested subqueries. Yes, I'm aware of them and have used them, but this question is really about the *result* of `SUBQUERY`. If we think of `SUBQUERY` as a function, what is its result and in what ways can it be used, other than with `@count`?

### UPDATE

Thanks to Mundi's research, it appears that aggregates like `@avg` do in fact work with `SUBQUERY`, particularly with an in-memory filter such as `filteredArrayUsingPredicate:`, but not with Core Data when the underlying data store is `NSSQLiteStoreType`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, think of nested subqueries. See Dave DeLong's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3815272/427083) that explains subquery in very simple terms.
2. The reason your `@avg` does not work is unknown because it should actually work on any collection that has the appropriate attributes required by the aggregate function.
3. See 1.: SUBQUERY returns a collection.

Here is the transcript of an experiment that proves that the subquery works as expected.

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class Department: NSManagedObject {
    var name = "Department"
    var employees = Set<Person>()

    convenience init(name: String) {
        self.init()
        self.name = name
    }
}

class Person: NSManagedObject {
    var name: String = "Smith"
    var salary: NSNumber = 0

    convenience init(name: String, salary: NSNumber) {
        self.init()
        self.name = name
        self.salary = salary
    }
}

let department = Department()
department.employees = Set ([
 Person(name: "Smith", salary: NSNumber(double: 30000)),
 Person(name: "Smith", salary: NSNumber(double: 60000)) ])


let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "SUBQUERY(employees, $e, $e.name = %@).@avg.salary > 44000", "Smith")

let depts = [department, Department()]
let filtered = (depts as NSArray).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(predicate)
```

The above returns exactly one department with the two employees. If I substitute 45000 in the predicate, the result will return nothing.

Comment: If the `@count` aggregate can be applied to `SUBQUERY`, is it not already a collection? Why can I say such things as `employees.@count` and `employees.@avg.salary` and `SUBQUERY().@count` but not `SUBQUERY().@avg.salary`?

Comment: To answer your question: clearly, the `avg` aggregate function needs more information from the collection being queried than just the `count`.

Comment: So you're saying that the result of a `SUBQUERY` expression is a count, rather than a filtered collection? That doesn't seem to make much sense. If that were true, we would say `SUBQUERY(...) > 0` and not `SUBQUERY(...).@count > 0`.

Comment: I think you and I must have different mental models of `SUBQUERY`. To me, it looks very much like a list comprehension in Haskell or Python, albeit with simpler syntax. Thus, it should return a collection of the filtered entities. If I can say `employees.@avg.salary`, I should be able to say `SUBQUERY(employees, ...).@avg.salary`, but I cannot. I suspect this is just a technical limitation of translating predicates into the underlying language, such as SQL or XPath.

Comment: In fact, if Dave DeLong can be counted an authority, he himself states that `SUBQUERY` returns a collection in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9813608/27779

Comment: I take back what I said. After some experiment I came to the conclusion that your initial supposition was correct. The error you get must be due to something else. I amended my answer and demonstrated points 1 and 2 (and 3, I guess).

Comment: OK, I'll do some more experimentation of my own.

Comment: Preliminarily, it appears that `@avg` works with `filteredArrayUsingPredicate` but *not* with a Core Data query that talks to the underlying data store.